# trying to pull a certain line of text from a pdf with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

im currently working on a program for work. i have to go through about 50 pdf's a day and go through and rename them. so im working on a program to pull the invoice number from the each pdf and rename it to that invoice number but currently all ive been able to do is get the author creator producer... ect. how can i pull just the invoice number from the pdf? im using pypdf2

ive looked all over the internet but cant find anything about this.

```
def pdf():
def extract_information(pdf_path):
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as f:
        pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
        information = pdf.getDocumentInfo()
        number_of_pages = pdf.getNumPages()

    txt = f"""
    Information about {pdf_path}: 

    Author: {information.author}
    Creator: {information.creator}
    Producer: {information.producer}
    Subject: {information.subject}
    Title: {information.title}
    Number of pages: {number_of_pages}
    """

    print(txt)
    return information

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = input("What is the name of the pdf?(be sure to add .pdf to the end of the name) ")
    extract_information(path)
```

i want to be able to pull an invoice number from a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use regular expression for that. I don't know exact format of your PDF but it should look somewhat like this:

```
import re

pdfDocument = ''' somestuff
asdad
dasdd   Invoice Number: 678903    other stuff

rest of the stuff '''
str2 = re.search(r'Invoice Number: [0-9]*', pdfDocument)
str2 = str2.group(0)
print(str2)
```

This will return just the 'Invoice Number: 678903' string. You may need to adjust the regexp acordingly. [regexr](https://regexr.com) is a very handy tool for designing regular expressions

EDIT:

It's more about the fromat of the invoice number. If it has some special keys except decimal digits you have to adjust the regexp. I found one tool that can find value based on it's location in the file but i never used it and i don't know if it will work in your case. Also i think you have to pay for it. Also i don't think i would trust them enought to handle my confidential data.[docparser](https://docparser.com/blog/extract-data-from-pdf/)

I think the easiest way is still to parse pdf to text and search with regexp. I figured out that perhaps parsing the pdf to txt might be troublesome for you. I would sugest using tika for that. It's easy to install if you have pip:

```
pip3 install tika
```

I then made some dummy pdf document with Latex and hidden invoice number in there:
[image: Dummy pdf]

Here is the code:

```
import re

from tika import parser

raw = parser.from_file('report.pdf')

pdfDocument = raw['content']

str2 = re.search(r'Invoice Number: [0-9]*', pdfDocument)
str2 = str2.group(0)
print(str2)
```

Comment: i tried this but couldnt get it to work i cant post what format my invoice is in due to it being confidential but could i pull the data based on its location on the page?